# Quarkus: extending graceful shutdown functionality

Tags: quarkus, graceful-shutdown

On application start I am initializing a map containing some client request data.

```
public void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
     // initializing a map
}
```

I would like to extend graceful shutdown functionality: my service should not shutdown until one of the following conditions is met:

- configured period of time has passed (quarkus.shutdown.timeout config property)
- all clients have responded (already supported by Quarkus -> HTTP requests)
- my custom map is empty

How can I subscribe to a shutdown event so I can check during graceful period if my custom map is empty?

Comment: Have you looked at `@Observes ShutdownEvent ev` as mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events?

Comment: @geoand Unfortunately, it is not helping because it will be triggered after graceful period of time has passed or all requests are finished. What I would like to achieve is to check if my custom map is empty during that graceful period. I tried to play with ShutdownListener (tried to implement it), but I failed. It seems to me like I maybe need to add new extension so I can somehow use ShutdownListenerBuildItem, but I wanted to check if it is the right way to do it...

Comment: You can certainly try. I admit I don't understand your use case fully, so I can't tell whether it will work or not